# Plot Grouped bar graph with calculated standard deviation in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I feel like this should be really easy to do, but I'm having a really hard time figuring this out.

I have a data frame

```
type <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
x <- rnorm(5)
y <- rnorm(5)
z <- rnorm(5) 
xsd <- sd(x)
ysd <- sd(y)
zsd <- sd(z)
df <- data.frame(type, x,y,z,xsd,ysd,zsd)
df



type           x          y         z       xsd       ysd       zsd
1    a -1.16788106  0.2260430 -1.16788106 0.8182508 0.7321015 0.9016335
2    b -0.09955193 -0.6647980 -0.09955193 0.8182508 0.7321015 0.9016335
3    c -0.87901053 -0.4269936 -0.87901053 0.8182508 0.7321015 0.9016335
4    d -0.87861339 -1.3669793 -0.87861339 0.8182508 0.7321015 0.9016335
5    e  0.84350228  0.4702580  0.84350228 0.8182508 0.7321015 0.9016335
```

and I need a grouped bar graph of the mean of `x`, `y`, and `z` by `type` with error bars showing the standard deviation for each variable. The standard deviation is in different columns `xsd`,`ysd`and `zsd`

I need to  plot the mean in the y axis, `type` grouping the `x`, `y`, `z` variables in the x axis.
I tried using `gather()`, to rearrange the data, but I'm not having any success...

Comment: Are x, y, z the values of the bar itself? Or do you want to plot the mean? Do you expect 15 bars or 3?

Comment: Is that how your real dataset looks like?

Comment: @AntoniosK yes, different names, but it's very similar. Just recreated it for reproducibility and readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let ggplot2 do the calculations for you:

```
install.packages("hmisc") # for mean_sdl

library(tidyverse)

type <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
x <- rnorm(5, 10, 5)
y <- rnorm(5, 8, 3)
z <- rnorm(5, 2, 4) 

df <- data.frame(type,x,y,z)

df_long <- df %>% 
  gather(variable, value, x:z)

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "col") + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, geom = "errorbar", width = .5, fun.args = list(mult = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know ggplot could do the calculations for you. This is very close to what I need. I just need to group the variables by `type`

Comment: What do you mean "group by type"? Should type be on the x axis?

Comment: the variable `type`  c("a","b","c","d","e"). Yes, it should be grouping the x, y and z variables

Comment: Then you will have 15 bars? That won't make sense, you have only 15 observations, you cant then get a standard deviation for a single observation.

Comment: you are completely correct. I realized my initial comment does not fully represent my data. However I was able to do what I needed with my real data.

Answer (score 1):

This example should help:

```
type <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
x <- rnorm(50,20, 5)
y <- rnorm(50, 25,1)
z <- rnorm(50, 40, 1) 

df <- data.frame(type, x,y,z)
df

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(x,value,-type) %>%
  group_by(type, x) %>%
  summarise(MEAN = mean(value),
            SD = sd(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, MEAN, fill=type))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=MEAN-SD, ymax=MEAN+SD), position = "dodge")
```